# Simple Query to Grab Max Value for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group

OK I have a table like this:

```
ID     Signal    Station    OwnerID
111     -120      Home       1
111     -130      Car        1
111     -135      Work       2
222     -98       Home       2
222     -95       Work       1
222     -103      Work       2
```

This is all for the same day. I just need the Query to return the max signal for each ID:

```
ID    Signal    Station    OwnerID
111   -120      Home        1
222   -95       Work        1
```

I tried using MAX() and the aggregation messes up with the Station and OwnerID being different for each record. Do I need to do a JOIN?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this?  Join your table with itself, and exclude the rows for which a higher signal was found.

```
select cur.id, cur.signal, cur.station, cur.ownerid
from yourtable cur
where not exists (
    select * 
    from yourtable high 
    where high.id = cur.id 
    and high.signal > cur.signal
)
```

This would list one row for each highest signal, so there might be multiple rows per id.

Comment: Yeah this does return duplicates if the Signal is the same for multiple Stations.

Comment: Edited so you get multiple rows per signal, but no duplicates.  Use Quassnoi's answer if you only want a random row from among those with the highest signal.

Comment: Yes i think this is working. I need to check the data. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Easy to understand and works great even 10 years later, thanks a lot!

Comment: what about the complexity though? Isn't this O(N^2)?

Answer (score 16):

You are doing a group-wise maximum/minimum operation. This is a common trap: it feels like something that should be easy to do, but in SQL it aggravatingly isn't.

There are a number of approaches (both standard ANSI and vendor-specific) to this problem, most of which are sub-optimal in many situations. Some will give you multiple rows when more than one row shares the same maximum/minimum value; some won't. Some work well on tables with a small number of groups; others are more efficient for a larger number of groups with smaller rows per group.

[Here's a discussion](http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html) of some of the common ones (MySQL-biased but generally applicable). Personally, if I know there are no multiple maxima (or don't care about getting them) I often tend towards the null-left-self-join method, which I'll post as no-one else has yet:

```
SELECT reading.ID, reading.Signal, reading.Station, reading.OwnerID
FROM readings AS reading
LEFT JOIN readings AS highersignal
    ON highersignal.ID=reading.ID AND highersignal.Signal>reading.Signal
WHERE highersignal.ID IS NULL;
```

Comment: The use of "reading" and "highersignal" aliases makes comprehension of the query a breeze! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In classic SQL-92 (not using the OLAP operations used by Quassnoi), then you can use:

```
SELECT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, t.Station, t.OwnerID
  FROM (SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS MaxSignal
          FROM t
          GROUP BY id) AS g
       JOIN t ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal;
```

(Unchecked syntax; assumes your table is 't'.)

The sub-query in the FROM clause identifies the maximum signal value for each id; the join combines that with the corresponding data row from the main table.

NB: if there are several entries for a specific ID that all have the same signal strength and that strength is the MAX(), then you will get several output rows for that ID.

---

Tested against IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50.FC3 running on Solaris 10:

```
+ CREATE TEMP TABLE signal_info
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    signal  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    station CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    ownerid INTEGER NOT NULL
);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(111, -120, 'Home', 1);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(111, -130, 'Car' , 1);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(111, -135, 'Work', 2);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(222, -98 , 'Home', 2);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(222, -95 , 'Work', 1);
+ INSERT INTO signal_info VALUES(222, -103, 'Work', 2);
+ SELECT g.ID, g.MaxSignal, t.Station, t.OwnerID
  FROM (SELECT id, MAX(Signal) AS MaxSignal
            FROM signal_info
            GROUP BY id) AS g
      JOIN signal_info AS t  ON g.id = t.id AND g.MaxSignal = t.Signal;

111     -120    Home    1
222     -95     Work    1
```

I named the table Signal_Info for this test - but it seems to produce the right answer.
This only shows that there is at least one DBMS that supports the notation.  However, I am a little surprised that MS SQL Server does not - which version are you using?

---

*It never ceases to surprise me how often SQL questions are submitted without table names.*

Comment: I get a "Syntax Error in FROM clause" error and it's pointing to the JOIN

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH q AS
         (
         SELECT  c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY signal DESC) rn
         FROM    mytable
         )
SELECT   *
FROM     q
WHERE    rn = 1
```

This will return one row even if there are duplicates of `MAX(signal)` for a given `ID`.

Having an index on `(id, signal)` will greatly improve this query.

Comment: Better to use the aggregate and jon method than creating a column. The optimiser can evaluate is as a whole: the computed column here needs calculated first so this more than likely needs a spool somewhere

Comment: If you have an index on this column (which you should), the join will be less efficient.

Comment: + not for SQL Server 200 just in case

Comment: I know, but with an index it's more efficient for SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Good to know. I just tested with 13k rows and 300k rows tables. IO is less, better for smaller table

Comment: Yours. Less logical reads, less scans. However, the % of batch shows a lot worse for larger table... but I tend to prefer IO stats. I did not check CPU though

Comment: this is my preferred way of solving this, especially if there are multiple maxima being tested.  e.g. in the event of a tie on "signal" column, take the max of owner id column.

Answer (score 2):

```
with tab(id, sig, sta, oid) as
(
select 111 as id, -120 as signal, 'Home' as station, 1 as ownerId union all
select 111, -130, 'Car',  1 union all
select 111, -135, 'Work', 2 union all
select 222, -98, 'Home',  2 union all
select 222, -95, 'Work',  1 union all
select 222, -103, 'Work', 2
) ,
tabG(id, maxS) as
(
   select id, max(sig) as sig from tab group by id
)
select g.*, p.* from tabG g
cross apply ( select  top(1) * from tab t where t.id=g.id order by t.sig desc ) p
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do using self join

```
SELECT  T1.ID,T1.Signal,T2.Station,T2.OwnerID
FROM (select ID,max(Signal) as Signal from mytable group by ID) T1
LEFT JOIN mytable T2
ON T1.ID=T2.ID and T1.Signal=T2.Signal;
```

Or you can also use the following query

```
SELECT t0.ID,t0.Signal,t0.Station,t0.OwnerID 
FROM mytable t0 
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 ON t0.ID=t1.ID AND t1.Signal>t0.Signal 
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, b.signal, a.station, a.owner from 
mytable a
join 
(SELECT ID, MAX(Signal) as Signal FROM mytable GROUP BY ID) b
on a.id = b.id AND a.Signal = b.Signal
```

Comment: @thegreekness: do you need to include an explicit AS between the table aliases?  mytable AS a JOIN (SELECT ...) AS b?  You shouldn't, but...

Comment: I've just realized - the ON condition must specify a join on signal too.

Comment: This may be the only efficient solution in the bunch.  But it does require a compound index (id, signal).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM StatusTable
WHERE Signal IN (
    SELECT A.maxSignal FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, MAX(Signal) AS maxSignal
        FROM StatusTable
        GROUP BY ID
    ) AS A
);
```

Answer (score 0):

select
 id,
 max_signal,
 owner,
 ownerId
FROM (
  select * , rank() over(partition by id order by signal desc) as max_signal from table 
)
where max_signal = 1;