# Using mysql i need to retrieve which are inserted last in every category

Tags: mysql

My prob in brief:

I have two tables namely category and product.

table: category

```
id     category

1      cat1

2      cat2

3      cat3

4      cat4
```

table: product

```
id  productName category

1    test1         1

2    test2         2

3    test3         3

4    test4         4

5    test5         2

6    test6         2
```

My prob is:

I need products which are inserted last in every category.

How to solve this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `create_time` timestamp when a new a product has been added, and retrieve the newest by category be something like:

```
select max(create_time),category from product group by category
```

Comment: `productName` can't be selected for `GROUP BY category` because the product name doesn't have a functional dependency on category. You will get an arbitrary product name from the category, not necessarily the same product as the one whose `create_time` matched `MAX(create_time)`. In other database software and ANSI SQL:92, this is simply an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of one of the most-common SQL questions asked here, the per-group maximum. See eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id) for a variety of approaches.

The one I often use is a null-self-left-join, to select the row which has no value above it:

```
SELECT p0.*
FROM product AS p0
LEFT JOIN product AS p1 ON p1.category=p0.category AND p1.id>p0.id
WHERE p1.id IS NULL
```

This is assuming that `id`​s are allocated in order so the highest is the most recent. Normally it wouldn't be a good idea to rely on identity as an ordering mechanism; you'd typically add an `added` timestamp to each row to work on instead.

(Note this and many other per-group maximum functions can return more than one row when two rows have identical order columns. If this is a problem it could be avoided by using a `UNIQUE` ordering column; as a primary key `id` is already that. You can get a single row even when there are two maxima using SQL:2003's useful but rather ugly `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` windowing functions, but this is not supported by MySQL.)