# SQL statement HAVING MAX(some+thing)=some+thing

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate, having

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Access 2003, it's complaining about this statement:

```
select cardnr
from change
where  year(date)<2009
group by cardnr
having max(time+date) = (time+date) and cardto='VIP'
```

What I want to do is, for every distinct cardnr in the table change, to find the row with the latest (time+date) that is before year 2009, and then just select the rows with cardto='VIP'.

This [validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser99/index.tml#parser) says it's OK, Access says it's not OK.

This is the message I get: "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'max(time+date)=time+date and cardto='VIP' and cardnr=' as part of an aggregate function."

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and the right way to do it? Thanks

Note: The field and table names are translated and do not collide with any reserved words, I have no trouble with the names.

Comment: What if you change the selec to `select cardnr, time, date, cardto...`?

Comment: Should't all the stuff in the having be in the where clause?

Comment: It's yet another per-group-maximum question! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id et al.

Comment: Time and Date are reserved words, and very ill-suited as field names in any database, seems to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to think of it like this - HAVING is applied after the aggregation is done.
Therefore it can not compare to unaggregated expressions (neither for time+date, nor for cardto).

However, to get the last (principle is the same for getting rows related to other aggregated functions as weel) time and date you can do something like:

```
SELECT cardnr
FROM change main
WHERE time+date IN (SELECT MAX(time+date) 
                    FROM change sub
                    WHERE sub.cardnr = main.cardnr AND 
                          year(date)<2009 
                          AND cardto='VIP')
```

(assuming that date part on your time field is the same for all the records; having two fields for date/time is not in your best interest and also using reserved words for field names can backfire in certain cases)

It works because the subquery is filtered only on the records that you are interested in from the outer query.

Applying the same year(date)<200 and cardto='VIP' to the outer query can improve performance further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to understand when the aggregate function is actually performed, it feels like it is done at the same time as the grouping takes place, even though the function is written inside the HAVING clause (in which I take it I have already "lost" rows and columns).

If I try your query, will it not just select the latest row of those that have cardto='VIP'? (If so, I realize it's just a question of moving cardto= to the outer query to make it do what I need.)

Comment: As for cardto='VIP' if you want to select only rows which have the MAX(time+date) and are cardto='VIP' at the same time, yes move it out. As for when the MAX, MIN and other occur - yes, you could say that HAVING and GROUP BY happen at the same time, the important part is the fact that while the DB is 'going through the records' (when the WHERE part is evaluated) you can not know the MAX yet of a particular record yet.