# Max rows by group

Tags: sql, oracle

Current SQL:

```
select t1.*
  from table t1
 where t1.id in ('2', '3', '4')
```

Current results:

```
id | seq
---+----
 3 |   5
 2 |   7
 2 |   5
 3 |   7
 4 |   3
```

Attempt to select maxes:

```
select t1.*
  from table t1
 where t1.id in ('2', '3', '4')
   and t1.seq = (select max(t2.seq)
                   from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id)
```

This obviously does not work since I'm using an `in` list. How can I adjust my SQL to get these expected results:

```
id | seq
---+----
 2 |   7
 3 |   7
 4 |   3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Query to Grab Max Value for each ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id)

Comment: Trying to figure out what would be wrong with : select id, max(seq) from t1 group by id having id in ('2','3','4');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group By is your friend:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(seq) seq
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY id
```

EDIT:  Response to comment.  To get the rest of the data from the table matching the max seq and id just join back to the table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id
        MAX(seq) as seq
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY id
) as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.seq = t2.seq
```

EDIT:  Gordon and Jean-Francois are correct you can also use the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to get the same result.  You need to check the performance difference for your application (I did not check).  Here is an example of that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY id 
        ORDER BY seq DESC) as row_num
        ,*
    FROM TABLE
) as TMP
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest approach is elusive.

Comment: @Michael Humelsine How do I do this if I'm selecting by `t.*`? My table actually has more fields than what I've given in the example.

Comment: @OP . . . In that case, you should use Jean-Francois's deleted answer.  `row_number()` is the way to go.

Comment: You could always use the [first](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm)/last aggregate functions to "keep" the values of the related columns.

Comment: @OP: Your opening post says ID and SEQ are the only columns.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL Query will give you max seq from individaul ID.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE t1.id in ('2', '3', '4')
   AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM t1 t2
                    WHERE t2.id = t1.id 
                    AND t2.seq > t1.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where (id,seq) in
(
select id,max(seq)
from table
group by id
having id in ('2','3','4')
);
```

That is if `id` and/or `seq` are completely part of the PK of that table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example, using the first/last method I mentioned earlier in the comments:

```
with sd as (select 3 id, 5 seq, 1 dummy from dual union all
            select 2 id, 7 seq, 2 dummy from dual union all
            select 2 id, 5 seq, 3 dummy from dual union all
            select 3 id, 7 seq, 4 dummy from dual union all
            select 3 id, 7 seq, 5 dummy from dual union all
            select 4 id, 3 seq, 6 dummy from dual)
select id,
       max(seq) max_seq,
       max(dummy) keep (dense_rank first order by seq desc) max_rows_dummy
from   sd
group by id;

        ID    MAX_SEQ MAX_ROWS_DUMMY
---------- ---------- --------------
         2          7              2
         3          7              5
         4          3              6
```

The `keep (dense_rank first order by ...)` bit is requesting to keep the values associated with the rank of 1 in the order list of rows. The `max(...)` bit is there in case more then one row has a rank of 1; it's just a way of breaking ties.