# Using mysql GROUP BY and ORDER BY for same request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've been trying `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in the same line to get what I want but it's not working.
I am using a while loop that is running thousands of names, checking for highest points in each city.
How do I get the name with highest points from each city, without repeating the same city twice?

This is what's in my database (in short):

```
ID City       Points    Name

1  NYC        16        Stan

2  London     24        Paul

3  NYC        11        Jeffrey

4  London     20        George

5  NYC        18        Ryan

$query = "SELECT `ID`, `City`, `Points`, `Name` FROM `table` GROUP BY `City` ORDER BY `Points`";
```

Gives me:

```
1 NYC 16 Stan

2 London 24 Paul
```

What I want it to give me:

```
2  London     24        Paul

5  NYC        18        Ryan
```

Comment: You need to use `HAVING` and MAX(points). I can give you more info, if you prepare an sqlfiddle with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join as

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t1.city=t2.city and t1.points < t2.points 
where t2.id is null;
```

Or using Uncorrelated subquery:

```
select t.* from table_name t 
join ( 
  select max(points) as points,city from table_name group by city
)x on x.city=t.city and x.points = t.points ;
```

Check the doc here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Or Subquery

```
select t.* from table_name t 
where not exists (
  select 1 from test t1 where t.city = t1.city and t.points < t1.points
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr Chakraborty! I ended up using Uncorrelated subquery. Proved easier for me to alter. It worked like a charm:)

Comment: But if I would like to apply a WHERE Gender='$male' it doesn't work for any of these three. How would I add WHERE to any of these?

Comment: `where` should work , but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Provide some sample data and desired result.

Comment: $query = "select t.* from stad  t join ( select max(points) as points,city from stad group by city )x on x.city=t.city and x.points = t.points where gender='$gender' ";

Comment: Desired result is same as above but also checking for gender, sorting out females for example.

Comment: Change the uncorrelated sub-query  as `select max(points) as points,city from table_name where gender = 'Female' group by city` this will return all female data with max values

Comment: If there is a same points available for same city with male and female then in that situation `(select max(points) as points,city,gender from table_name where gender = 'Female' group by city,gender)x on x.city=t.city and x.points=t.points and x.gender=t.gender`

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I need, thank you so much! Your last answer was actually what I really needed to know.

Comment: select max(points) as points,city from table_name where gender = 'Female' group by city. I'm using this line now since I don't want a same points available for same city but.... Im not getting the name and id, only points and city

Comment: Post a different question.

Answer (score 1):

That's a [groupwise maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id), one of the most commonly-asked SQL questions. 
You can try something like this,

```
SELECT tab1.*
FROM @Table AS tab1
LEFT JOIN @Table AS tab2 
     ON tab1.City=tab2.city  AND tab2.points > tab1.points
WHERE tab2.City IS NULL;
```