# SQL when one column has duplicate rows, then select row where other column is the min value

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
mt.id, mt.otherId, mt.name, mt.myChar, mt.type
1      10            stack      U          "question"  
2      10            stack      D  
3      30            stack      U          "question"
4      10            stack      U          "whydownvotes"
```

And I want only 
rows with id 2 and 3 returned (without using the id, otherid as parameter) and ensuring name and type are matching against parameters. And when there is a duplicate otherId = then return the row with min myChar value.  So far I have this :

```
select mt.* from myTable mt
where (mt.myChar = 'U' AND (mt.name = 'stack' AND mt.type LIKE '%question%'))
or (mt.myChar = 'D' and mt.name = 'stack')
```

So where otherID is 10, I want the row with min char value 'D'. I am going to need a subquery or group using min(myChar) ... ?

How do i remove the first row from the sql fiddle (without using the id):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579a/1

*edit*
Jeepers, whats with the downvotes, its clear question isn't it ? There is even a sql fiddle.

Comment: `where id in (2, 3)`.  I think you should edit your question and describe the logic for choosing those two particular rows.

Comment: So you want to select the record with the min value for the `mt.myChar` right.

Comment: @CoderofCode yes min char value when duplicate otherid

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet ansi please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755918/simple-query-to-grab-max-value-for-each-id

Answer (score 2):

If this is SQL Server, then you can do it in two steps like this:

```
WITH filtered AS (
  SELECT
    mt.*,
    minType = MIN(mt.type) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.otherId)
  FROM
    dbo.myTable AS mt
  WHERE (mt.myChar = 'U' AND mt.name = 'stack' AND mt.type LIKE '%question%')
     OR (mt.myChar = 'D' AND mt.name = 'stack')
)
SELECT
  id,
  otherId,
  name,
  myChar,
  type
FROM
  filtered
WHERE
  type = minType
;
```

The `filtered` subquery is basically your current query but with an additional column that holds minimum `type` values per `otherId`. The main query filters the `filtered` set further based on the `type = minType` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want is  a `groupwise maximum`, one of the most commonly-asked SQL questions You can try as , This query should work on any `DBMS`. But If you are using the `SQL SERVER` then you can use the `Row_Number()` which is very  easy to use.Here `myTable` is your table.

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM myTable AS t0
LEFT JOIN myTable AS t1 ON t0.otherId = t1.otherId  AND t1.myChar < t0.myChar
WHERE t1.myChar IS NULL;
```

[Here is sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c579a/4)